# Spring security autoconfiguration in 2.1.10

Tags: spring-boot

I have tried everything but I cant seems to disable auto-configuration of spring security in a Spring boot 2.1.10 - I think the autoconfiguration seems to be triggered by the actuator but I tried excluding almost every possible class but still seems to get the filter chains introduced. It worked briefly when I had the configuration through the properties file but stopped working again.

I have tried

`@SpringBootApplication (exclude = { ManagementContextAutoConfiguration.class, UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementContextAutoConfiguration.class})`

Also tried with properties -

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration

Can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's how we disabled Spring Security in Spring Boot 2.X

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Tried this but it didnt work - I think the issue is that there is a dependent project which is bringing actuator 2.0 dependency. The actuator management endpoint seems to be overriding this config.